# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i \times i! = (n+1)! - 1$ by induction

Tags: induction

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i = 1}^{k + 1} i(i!) & = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} i(i!) + (k + 1)(k + 1)!\\
                           & = (k + 1)! - 1 + (k + 1)(k + 1)! & \text{by the induction hypothesis}\\
                           & = (1 + k + 1)(k + 1)! - 1\\
                           & = (k + 2)(k + 1)! - 1\\
                           & = (k + 2)! - 1
\end{align*}

I have a question from this post solving the problem
[Prove by induction that $\sum_{i=1}^n i!\times i=(n+1)!-1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813940/prove-by-induction-that-sum-i-1n-i-times-i-n1-1-for-all-n-in-mathbb)

How does the person go from 
$                           = (k + 2)(k + 1)! - 1\\
                           = (k + 2)! - 1$

at the very end? I don't understand how the permutation of $(k+1)!$ and (k+2) are able to combine into $(k+2)!$

Comment: Consider an example, say with $k=3$:

$$(k+2)(k+1)!=(3+2)(3+1)!=5\cdot4!=5(4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1)=5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1=5!=(3+2)!=(k+2)!$$

Comment: ah that makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 7):

It is because, by definition, $n! = n(n-1)!$ and $0! = 1$. Just take $n=k+2$.

Answer (score 0):

Why not showing it directly?

\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{i=1}^{n} i\cdot i!
& = & \sum_{i=1}^{n} (i+1-1)\cdot i! \\
& = & \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left((i+1)!- i!\right) \\
& \stackrel{telescoping}{=} & (n+1)! - 1\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: The OP might wonder how you got from $(i+1)i!$ to $(i+1)!$....